# Error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code = EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode = 0x0)" Using Swift SpriteKit

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, crash, uibutton

I am trying to run a GameScene function in GameViewController and am receiving the error mentioned above. Here is the basics of the code:

This is called in GameScene:

```
func resetPosition(){
     someNode!.position = otherPosition! //this is the line with the error - otherPosition IS called previously as a CGPoint
}
```

And in GameViewController:

```
let gameScene = GameScene.self()

func reset(){ // reset is called by a UIButton
     gameScene.resetPosition()
}
```

The simulator opens and runs fine, but once the button linked to *reset* is pressed, the app crashes. If you need more code I will be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if either `someNode` or `otherPosition` is nil. You say that `otherPosition` is called earlier, so it must be `someNode` then.

What happens if you try to unwrap `someNode` before updating the position of it?

```
if let someNode = someNode {
   someNode.position = otherPosition
} else {
    print("someNode was nil")
}
```

Comment: Yes, someNode came out nil. The error went away when replacing the exclamation point on someNode with a question mark, but the problem remains with someNode being nil and nothing happens when the button is pressed. Any thoughts on why someNode is nil? It is added to the scene and all actions placed on it run without error.

Comment: how is `someNode` declared? And is the reset function called at some point after the `gameScene` has been released perhaps?

Comment: I replaced the code in the function with an SKAction to move the node so otherPosition, but the button still did nothing. My next test was to call the function when the screen was touched, and this did work which suggests to me that the issue is in the function call within GameViewController. Any suggestions?

Comment: gameScene and the reset function are both declared in the viewDidLoad within GameViewController.

Comment: have you declared your `reset` function inside the `viewDidLoad` function?

Comment: No sorry, they are both inside the GameViewController Class

Comment: ah OK, you got me there :-)

But if you're declaring `gameScene` in the viewDidLoad function, how can you see it in the `reset` function? 

And I just noticed the `GameScene.self()` thing. Why not just `let gameScene = GameScene()`

Comment: Both are in the GameViewController class. And using GameScene.self() seemed to have the same effects as GameScene()

Comment: OK, what happens if you just declare the `GameScene` in the top of your `GameViewController` class like so: `let gameScene = GameScene()` instead of in the `viewDidLoad` function

Comment: Perhaps it was my button declaration (the button was made programmatically). I will confirm that it was made correctly.

Comment: Tested the button with a print statement and worked perfectly. I will do more research on calling functions from separate classes.

Comment: Might be a good idea. I haven't seen your code, but it does sound as if the way the `gameScene` object is declared may be wrong. Try adding it at the top as I suggested above maybe and see if that helps you.

Comment: I see from your other question that you got it working. Good. Was my answer correct?

Comment: Yes they were declared in positions where gameeScene was not seen by reset()

Comment: Glad that you figured it out. Good luck with Sprite Kit :-)